# HTML / CSS to mp4 or gif

Tags: video, html, gif

Is it any Javascript or React library, which would render part of an html and css to mp4 of GIF? I would use this gif is social sharing, it would be refered in an og:video field.

I would transform section in this: http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/chat/

to this: [image]